# SQL - Join table on multiple IDs and return query depending whether data present

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

Firstly, hopefully the title helps explain it, apologies if not. Was not sure best way of explaining what I am after in a title.

I have three tables. Outcomes, Type and Client.

The Outcomes and Client tables are linked by `Outcomes.Client_ID = Client.ID`

The Type table consists of reasons for not reaching an outcome. Fields include `Type.ID`, `Type.Description` and a few others. `Type.Description` includes all the different reasons.

The Outcomes table consists of various fields but primarily has columns for linking the ID for each of the different types as follows:

```
Outcomes.Outcomes1aMain_ID
Outcomes.Outcomes1aSecond_ID
Outcomes.Outcomes1bMain_ID
Outcomes.Outcomes1bSecond_ID
Outcomes.Outcomes2aMain_ID
Outcomes.Outcomes2aSecond_ID
```

and so on.

These Outcomes are linked each by `Outcomes.Outcomes1aMain_ID = Type.ID`…….

My objective is to create a report of Clients and reasons per outcome as follows:

`Client.Name, Outcome 1a, Outcome 1b, Outcome 2a, Outcome 2b`….Each of these *Outcomes* may have more than one reason. Therefore under each *Outcome* the query would be `Outcomes1aMain_ID + Outcomes1aSecond_ID`. Bearing in mind the `_ID` would be replaced by the `Type.Description`

I was hoping there was a better way of doing it rather then joining the `Type` table numerous (60) times and then querying each instance. Some outcomes will be `NULL` so I would also have to use a combination of `CASE` and `+` to get each Outcome.

My thought was of utilising the `XML PATH` to display the results but I am not sure how best to get the data first.

Unless joining each instance is the best way to go.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide some data samples and expected output, its hard to understand what exactly you want to achieve here.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have a lousy data structure, where you are storing values in columns instead of separate rows in a junction table.  That complicated many of the query you would want to run.

Comment: I have edited it slightly. @GordonLinoff I agree. It is far from great and gives me no end of grief. Hence my difficulty in even being able to explain it. Sadly this is what I have been handed. I appreciate you looking at it though. Worst case, I go the long way round with the multiple individual joins.

Comment: What about using a function and calling it to "lookup" the values each time instead of a join for every one?  eg(GetType(Outcomes.Outcomes1aMain_ID, getType(Outcomes1aSecond_ID)) I'd be a bit concerned about performance with this approach however.